# Adding dictionary to Pandas dataframe column based on value in the dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

members = [('Chicago', 'IL', '1058'), ('New York', 'NY', '3425'), 
          ('St. Louis', 'MO', '8854')]
labels = ['City', 'State', 'member_id']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(members, columns = labels)

   City      State   member_id
0  Chicago   IL      1058
1  New York  NY      3425
2  St. Louis MO      8854
```

I also have a list of dictionaries, which is shorter than the dataframe, similar to this:

```
x = [{'name':'Sue', 'age':'24', 'id':'3425'}, {'name':'Tom', 'age':'37', 'id':'1058'}]
```

I want to put the dictionary from the list into a new column in the dataframe called 'new_col', based on the id. In this case, the 'id' from the dictionary would relate to the 'member_id' in the dataframe. In addition, the output should only have rows that had added a dictionary.

The expected output would be something like this:

```
   City      State   member_id  new_col
0  Chicago   IL      1058       {'name':'Tom', 'age':'37', 'id':'1058'}
1  New York  NY      3425       {'name':'Sue', 'age':'24', 'id':'3425'}
```

I have tried creating a new dataframe just with those values, but can't seem to connect the two. I have also tried to add a new column, and then add the dictionary by iterating, to be later filtered:

```
df['new_col'] = None
for key, value in df['member_id'].iteritems():
    for n in x:
        id = str(n['id'])
        if id == str(value):
            df.loc[key, 'new_col'] = n
df = df[(df['new_col'] != None)]
```

It raises a ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series, but I'm not worried about that because I think my whole approach is wrong. There must be an easier way to do this than for loops within for loops, especially since this is a very large dataset. What's the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict` of `dict` with key `id`:

```
print ({int(i['id']):i for i in x})
{3425: {'id': '3425', 'age': '24', 'name': 'Sue'}, 
 1058: {'id': '1058', 'age': '37', 'name': 'Tom'}}

df['new'] = df.member_id.map({int(i['id']):i for i in x})
print (df)
        City State  member_id                                         new
0    Chicago    IL       1058  {'id': '1058', 'age': '37', 'name': 'Tom'}
1   New York    NY       3425  {'id': '3425', 'age': '24', 'name': 'Sue'}
2  St. Louis    MO       8854                                         NaN
```

Last if need remove rows with `NaN` in `new` column add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['new'] = df.member_id.map({int(i['id']):i for i in x})
df = df.dropna(subset=['new'])
print (df)
       City State  member_id                                         new
0   Chicago    IL       1058  {'id': '1058', 'age': '37', 'name': 'Tom'}
1  New York    NY       3425  {'id': '3425', 'age': '24', 'name': 'Sue'}
```

Comment: My data actually had member_id as a string, but that was an easy fix by taking out the int(). You've ended hours of torment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make the two sources of data to share an index

```
s_x = pd.Series(x)
s_x.index = s_x.apply(lambda x:int(x['id']))
new_df = df.set_index('member_id')
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, s_x],axis=1)
print new_df
```

output is:

```
        City    State   0
1058    Chicago IL  {u'age': u'37', u'name': u'Tom', u'id': u'1058'}
3425    NewYork NY  {u'age': u'24', u'name': u'Sue', u'id': u'3425'}
8854    StLouis MO  NaN
```

However, more useful would be to make the dict keys as columns by doing:

```
df_x = pd.DataFrame(x)
df_x.index = df_x['id'].astype('int32')
new_df = df.set_index('member_id')
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df_x],axis=1)
print new_df
```

output is:

```
      City     State  age  id  name
1058  Chicago    IL   37  1058  Tom
3425  NewYork    NY   24  3425  Sue
8854  StLouis    MO  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Are you sure it is correct? There is not join for `id` with `member_id`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. The dictionary is not in any particular order, that's why I need to link the 'id' with 'member_id'. Because they're different lengths, this also leaves a length of values error. I've made edits to the question.

Comment: Didn't notice that. I'll post a fix shortly

Comment: Posted a fix and some bonus :)